# Why close/delete questions about simulations?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Recently today two questions about simulations that I worked on were closed/deleted.  Is this just a coincidence or is somebody going around removing questions about simulations because they disagree with the idea?

[What actually is a simulation, formally?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78139/what-actually-is-a-simulation-formally)

- Closed as "off-topic"?  The simulation hypothesis is not off-topic for philosophy!  And of course a formal definition of "simulation" would be directly relevant to the simulation hypothesis.  How can we philosophically justify the idea that consciousness could exist within a simulation if we can't rigorously say what a simulation is?

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78383/isnt-the-simulation-argument-just-the-boltzmann-brain-problem

- Not a great question, but maybe it would have been better to improve the question and fix tags, seeing how I'd already answered it.  Anyway I don't care about this one really, it's just suspicious that it was closed within hours of the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the first question, I suggested what the problem may be in a comment. I think what happened here is that we have a lot of text and a lot of thought going on which basically blurs the question proper, which gets drowned and fuzzier. This is probably why it ended up closed as off-topic since it is not clear what the actual question is when you give partial or possible answers.

Just trim it down to the actual problem and maybe your motivation to ask this and it should be a good candidate for reopening.

As of the second one, it is a post from a network-troll whose posts are deleted per policy, even if that one was one of the few instances where there maybe was an actual on-topic question involved. So this instance is not at all about the topic.

Comment: Is the network troll the user whose suspension expires in 20**9**2?

Comment: @Fizz Nope, that's a much older inglorious chapter you are talking about.